# In the context of factor analysis, are the terms 'factor' and 'latent variable' synonymous?

Tags: factor-analysis

I realise that the term factor has additional applications in other areas (e.g. in ANOVA), but it seems to me that in factor analysis the two terms are used synonymously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. Latent construct also synonymous.

Comment: I feel this answer (to my mind, a correct one) should be turned into a comment, unless some explanatory body is attached to it.

Comment: Yeah I was feeling the same way a bit when I wrote it, but then I realized that the question was a yes/no question... What would you recommend adding?